# Troubleshooting an Ubuntu kernel crash from an unknown disk issue

Tags: 18.04, crash, disk

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and it appears my Ubuntu kernel crashed with an error pointing to an `EXT4-fs (sbd1): write access unavailable` message on the terminal screen. In checking all my logs in /var/log after a reboot yields that at the time, a repeating list of `^@` characters appear to have started filling both my syslog and kernel log with no preceding messages pointing to an actual error. The strange part about this error message is that I have no `sbd1` drive mounted. Thoughts?

I'm also seeing that I have no swap space activated. Not sure if that would cause an issue.

[lsblk command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNG8n.png)

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ^@ characters that you see in /var/log/syslog are a byproduct of the kernel panic.

The sdb1 errors may come from a flash drive, phone, or external HDD/SSD, that's connected to a USB port, or from an incorrect entry in /etc/fstab.

For the swap space problem, edit your question and show me `free -h` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid` and `sudo fdisk -l`.